# SharePoint CSOM File.LinkingUrl property not found

Tags: 2013, development, client-object-model

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and referencing v16 of both `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` in a .NET4.0 application.

According to the MSND page for a [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file_members.aspx) object, there should be a [LinkingUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.linkingurl.aspx) property. But Visual Studio is saying that property does not exist.

I also downloaded [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) but that didn't fix it.

What am I missing with this seemingly simple issue?

Comment: If you use object browser and view client dll can you see that property?

Comment: I tried that also and the property isn't there. I thought I had an older version of the DLL at first but I can't find anything newer than v16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK [File class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.aspx) does not expose `LinkingUrl` property in SharePoint **2013** CSOM API  (version **15.0.4420.1017**) including the [latest version April 2015 CU](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/dev/Assemblies/15) (**15.0.4711.1000**)

Since `File.LinkingUrl` property returns an absolute file url, you could consider the following approach in SharePoint 2013 CSOM API:

```
using (var ctx = ClientContext(webUri))
{
   var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
   ctx.Load(file, f => f.ListItemAllFields["EncodedAbsUrl"]);
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
   Console.WriteLine(file.ListItemAllFields["EncodedAbsUrl"]);
}
```

### What about SharePoint Online CSOM API?

If you are developing application for *SharePoint Online* you could install the latest version of SDK from [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) or alternatively via Nuget Package Manager: [Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM).

Example

```
using (var ctx = GetContext(webUri, userName, password))
 {
        var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
        ctx.Load(file);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(file.LinkingUrl);
 }
```

where

```
public static ClientContext GetContext(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
     var securePassword = new SecureString();
     foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
     return new ClientContext(webUri) {Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword)};
}
```

Comment: Using the `EncodedAbsUrl` field worked.